# Zend Label decorator, is each one a new instance?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have 2 text elements in a Zend form. When I add a Zend decorator to each of these elements, like the Label decorator here, does anyone know if a new instance of the Label decorator is created? or is the same instance reused? Does it try to use singleton pattern?

```
$text1->addDecorator('Label');

$text2->addDecorator('Label');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Label decorator instance is created for each text element. Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract is not a Singleton.